# ArrayList contains does not its thing

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an list with AppPackages names. 
I want to hide some of them, so I got a SQLIte Database which include the packageNames which should be hided.

The size is 1 and there is a Package named = "com.xiaomi.midrop".

So I have a List; AppDrawer has a getter and setter 
`private String packageName; private String appName;` 
And the List has a Getter and Setter too:
Only `String packageName;`

I have a for Loop with the resolveNames so the PackageNames...

```
for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfosAppDrawer){
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(listHide.contains(new AppHide(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))){
            Toast.makeText(context, "HIDE IT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

        }
        appDrawerList.add(new AppDrawer(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, (String) resolveInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager())));
    }
```

But it always doesn't work, even the list (AppHide) is filled with one PackageName.

Comment: what is listHide & its type?

Comment: It is List<AppHide>

Comment: try with 
for ( int j = 0 ; j < listHide.size();j++){
if ( listhide.get(j).getPackageName().contains(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))
}

Comment: please let me know if it is working or not

Comment: No. If I have two items in the listHide it adds two same items at appDrawerList

Comment: this is because 
appDrawerList.add(new AppDrawer(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, (String) resolveInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager())));

is out of if/else condition. So it will add every time.

so put this in else part

Comment: No it is inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200195/discussion-between-kishan-maurya-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this logic. You need to iterate over listHide to check for each package name.

```
  for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfosAppDrawer) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    boolean isForDrawer = true;
    for (AppHide hide : listHide) {
    if (hide.getPackagEName().contentEquals(packageName)) {
    isForDrawer = false;
    Toast.makeText(context, "HIDE IT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    if (isForDrawer) {
    appDrawerList.add(new AppDrawer(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, (String) resolveInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager())));
    }
    }
```